# Send $_POST data in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

First of all , thanks for your interest, well let me explain.
I want to get $_POST['Division'] from and dropdown list :

`

```
<select name="Division" onchange="setImage2(this);">
   <option value="1">Bronze</option>
   <option value="2">Silver</option>
   <option value="3">Gold</option>
   <option value="4">Platinum</option>
   <option value="5">Diamond</option>
</select>
```

`

And I try to send this like so :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test_fnc.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: { "callFunc1": $_POST['Division'], "callFunc1A": "1"},
  success: function(response) { alert(response); }
});
```

But it's not working , can I request your help ?
Thanks alot !
Regards.

Comment: Where is the JS-Code you have there at the bottom of your post located in your file-structure? I don't understand what you want to POST with the JS

Comment: what this function is doing `setImage2(this);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this insted.

```
 var sel = document.getElementsByName("Division")[0];
 var callFunc1_var= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
 your ajax code...
 data: { "callFunc1": callFunc1_var, "callFunc1A": "1"},
 your ajax code..
```

Comment: Also you need to retrieve the first element: `var sel = document.getElementsByName("Division")[0];`

Comment: Works perfectly , exactly what I wanted ! Thanks alot !

Comment: @Robert I'm more used to using id in my work, so it's natural that mistakes come when I use name of element, So thanks for the help.

Comment: @Solber Accept the response if she helped you, this way you are helping people in the future, who have the same problem that you had.

Answer (score 1):

This is php code, so you can make it work like this:

```
data: { "callFunc1": <?php echo $_POST['Division']; ?>, "callFunc1A": "1"}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but when I put this , It's not working , it just freezing and doing nothing :/

Comment: @Solber you need to use this code inside php file wrap to `<script></script>` this code will not work inside the js file

Comment: Hello , finally I used something else , I'm in a php file but I used this : "callFunc1": select.options[select.selectedIndex].value

Comment: @Solber your question title takin about `$_POST` and this is a php code .. with your case you need to get the selected option value and this is just the js code .. so please edit your question title to *How to pass selected option value to php*

Comment: @Solber is your `ajax` code inside `setImage2` function ??

Answer (score 1):

1) you must replace `$_POST['Division']` in `$.ajax` to `$('#Division > option:selected').val()`

2) you must replace `<select name="Division">` in `html` to `<select id="Division">`

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery browser-side:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test_fnc.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: { "callFunc1": $('[name=Division]').val(), "callFunc1A": "1"},
  success: function(response) { alert(response); }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but it don't work with a dropdown list, it just send a 0, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: It should not. Do you have another element.name "Division"? Try adding an id='Division' to your element. Then use `$('#Division').val()`

Comment: @Solber  what this function is doing `setImage2(this);`?

Answer (score 0):

So to close my subject, here is the solution :

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'test_fnc.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { "callFunc1": select.options[select.selectedIndex].value, "callFunc1A": "1"},
      success: function(response) { alert(response); }
  });
```

Comment: What is the `select` var?

Comment: Var that i get from the fonction called by my dropdwon list !

Comment: Ok, we missed that part.

Comment: How is it $_POST data then?